# Webform Module and Elements Module

Tags: webforms, forms

I have a hook that i wrote to include the elements fields (i.e, telfield) in a webform. The field doesnt take on the same css as the rest of the fields which means I probably need to add a style to the CSS for it. However, I'm trying to figure out a way to implement this globally so that I will be accepted as a regular form component since I have over 40 different themes that this will be applying to.

This is an attempt to avoid having to go into each them and adding the style.

Thanks,

Comment: If my answer was useful do not forget to mark it as acepted otherwise anybody in the comunity will help you again. Greetings

Comment: it wasnt that helpful. but thanks for the answer. how do i vote?

Comment: click the symbol √ at the left of my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no way to add a stylesheet and be global for all the themes you have inside sites/all/themes

The unic way is that all your different 40 themes were subthemes of one parent theme then you can have your styles in the parent theme and all your subthemes will inherit the styles of the parent, there is no other way...